# How do you separate the Column names and its values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, dataset

I wanted to import this [dataset][1] named "wind.data" to perform some operations on it but I couldn't find a way to turn it into a proper table-like structure.
This is how it's looking like after importing:
[wind dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5FRY.png).
I tried using `sep=' '` parameter in `pd.read_csv('wind.data', sep=' ')` but it's not working.
How do I separate the column names and their respective values from this dataset?

[1]:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is not comma (or any other character) separated but is fixed width formatted.

Instead of trying to force `read_csv` to handle it correctly, you should use `read_fwf`.

```
df = pd.read_fwf("wind.data", header=1)
```

Comment: I think this is more appropriate than my answer for the use case of OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pd.read_csv('wind.data', delimiter=r'\s+')
```

Because there is not always a single space between columns.